# Let $C_n$ be a cyclic group. Show that $C_6 ≅ C_3 × C_2$.

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

Let be $C_n$ a cyclic group. Show that $C_6$ $\cong$  $C_3$ $\times$ $C_2$ .

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Well done for formatting the Q! On @Mark, there are two reasons for his comment. (1) to help people understand your difficulty - it is easy to waste time dealing with points that the person who set the question has already grasped, (2) to encourage those setting questions not to be too lazy! People here expect you to make some effort to answer a question yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to create a isomorphism between C6 and C3 x C2.

Comment: @johny What is the order of the element $(a,b)$ where $1\ne a\in C_3$ and $1\ne b\in C_2$?

Comment: Simply try that $(x, y) \mapsto xy$ where $x \in C_3, y \in C_2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about order of $(1,1) \in C_3 \times C_2$ may guide you to find the answer.

Comment: Which specific isomorphism do i have to use

Comment: @johny First prove its order is $6$. Then it leads you to continue.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is cyclic, it is abelian. By Cauchy's theorem there exist subgroups $A$ and $B$ such that $|A|= 2$ and $|B|=3$. Since $\gcd(2,3) = 1$, we have that the intersection of $A$ and $B$ is the identity, therefore we have that $AB=C_6$ ($AB$ is a group because $ C_6 $ is abelian). We have that every element $c \in C_6 $ is of the form $ab$, where $a$ is in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, now, use the homomorphism $f(c) = (a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

What about
$$[k]_6\mapsto ([k]_2,[k]_3) \ \ ?$$

Comment: Do you know how to prove that this is isomorphism